# Creating a Call of Duty Ghosts account

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

Apparently they've gotten rid of the COD Ghosts app so how am i supposed to create an account or a clan? When i click on barracks in the multiplayer menu the only thing it shows is Leaderboards and Reset Stats.

Comment: I notice the above question has been asked, but the answer requires the app. Unfortunately, this still constitutes a duplicate question, simply the original question no longer has a valid answer. The appropriate course to take is to revisit the original question. I have placed a bounty on it requesting an up-to-date answer, so the question should be updated soon-ish to reflect the current situation.